# Creating rule-based style for attribute between two values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, rule-based

It seems a pretty straightforward rule but I believe I am missing something simple. Let's say I have, in my attributes table, an attribute called `"NumberOfFloors"`, with values between 1 and 35.

I am trying to add colours to the different objects (buildings) by creating rules in the following way:

```
 1 <= "NumberOfFloors" <= 3
 4 <= "NumberOfFloors" <= 6
 ...
```

And so on until reaching the highest building.

However, so far, it is displaying all the symbols on the colour of the highest value, represented by this rule `32 <= "NumberOfFloors" <= 35`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rewriting your rules like this:

```
"NumberOfFloors" >=1 AND "NumberOfFloors" <= 3
"NumberOfFloors" >=4 AND "NumberOfFloors" <= 6
...
"NumberOfFloors" >=32 AND "NumberOfFloors" <= 35
```

This should work fine for integer values, such as number of floors in a building. However, if you want to include values between the integers, I would do something like this:

```
"NumberOfFloors" > 1 AND "NumberOfFloors" <= 4
"NumberOfFloors" > 4 AND "NumberOfFloors" <= 7
...
"NumberOfFloors" > 32 AND "NumberOfFloors" <= 36
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fezter. This, indeed, works.

In case anyone is interested, I ended up also going for a more, perhaps, annoying way that also works. Creating individual rules for each number of floors, like this, and assigning the appropriate colour to each of them:

 "NumberOfFloors" = 18